# Exports in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Ok, i have route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var articles = require('../model/articles.js');

router.get('/all', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json(articles.getAll());
  console.log( "From route: " + articles.getAll());
});
module.exports = router;
```

and, i have model:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "rest_news",
    password: "rest_news",
    database: "rest_news"
});
exports.getAll = function () {
    con.query('SELECT * FROM articles', function(err, rows){
        if(err) {
            return err;
        } else {
            console.log("From model:  " + rows);
            return rows;
        }
    });
};
```

i need get all articles from mysql, im use for that model **articles**, and method **getAll()**. What i see in console:

```
From route: undefined
GET /article/all 200 22.802 ms - -
From model:  [object Object],[object Object]
From model:  [object Object],[object Object]
```

getAll() work in second time, why?

Comment: Does not work because you are treating asynchronous code like synchronous code. The getAll function does not return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a callback function :

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "rest_news",
    password: "rest_news",
    database: "rest_news"
});
exports.getAll = function (callbackFunction) {
    con.query('SELECT * FROM articles', callbackFunction);
};
```

---

And now in your route do:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var articles = require('../model/articles.js');

router.get('/all', function(req, res, next) {
  articles.getAll(function(err, articles){
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({message: 'Ups something bad happened!'});
    }else{
        res.json(articles);
    }
  })
});
module.exports = router;
```

explanation: node uses callback to notify the main loop that something happened. In your code when you say :

```
  res.json(articles.getAll());
```

you are actually sending back undefined, that's why articles exsistt inside your query function, because that part of the code executes after the articles are fetched and `res.json(articles.getAll())` executes right after you enter the model function and send the query to the sql db.

Comment: yep, that work, sorry for duplicate.

Comment: Can you please give example of exports.getall for mongodb??

Comment: are you using mongoose or mongodb driver?